# Check which condition failed in complex sql query statement

Tags: mysql

I want to know which condition from where clause of SQL query fails.
For example I have below statement

```
SELECT * from Users where status != 'inactive'
AND ptype != 'test' AND ptype != 'test1' 
AND (p_name NOT IN ('ptest', 'ptest0', 'ptest1', 'ptest2') OR p_name IS NULL)
AND (p_m_c  NOT LIKE '%pmcestt%' 
OR (ptype LIKE 'SomeOthertest%' AND p_m_c IS NULL)
OR (TType = 'Broad' AND p_m_c IS NULL)
OR p_m_c IN ('pmctest', 'pmctest0', 'pmctest1', 'pmctest2', 'pmctest3',
'pmctest4', 'pmctest5', 'pmctest6', 'pmctest7', 'pmctest8'))
```

How can I know which condition failed, and get that condition?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check conditions you will have to move condition statement in `WHERE` clause to CASE statement for each condition in `SELECT` list apart from columns of table Users.

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN status !='inactive' THEN 1 else 0 end as statusTag,
       CASE WHEN ptype !='test' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as ptypeTag,
       .
       .
       CASE WHEN p_m_c IN ('pmctest', 'pmctest0', 'pmctest1', 'pmctest2', 'pmctest3',
'pmctest4', 'pmctest5', 'pmctest6', 'pmctest7', 'pmctest8') THEN 1 else 0 end as p_m_cTag

FROM Users
```

This will generate list of columns for each table row indicating value 1 if condition is satisfied or 0 if condition is false for that particular row.